# Generating and serving files created by a Python script on Heroku (Node/Express server)

Tags: python, node.js, heroku

I'm working on a site that collects textual input from a number of users and then gives all that input to a user with another role after a set amount of time. The user who is given access to all the input needs to be able to export all the text as a word document.

Right now, on my local machine, a button on the page makes a db call for all the text, and uses the fs npm module to write the correct set of input to a raw text document in a format the pyton script can understand. I then use the docx module in python to read the text and write the formatted input into the word document, saving it into the public directory in my server. I can navigate to it manually after that.

I can automate it locally by writing a simple cron job that waits for the contents of the raw text file to change, firing the python program when that happens and having the link to the word doc appear after some timeout.
My question is how would I get this to work on my heroku site? Simply having python isn't enough, because I need to install the docx module with pip. Beyond that, I still need to have a scheduled check for the raw text file to change to fire the python script. Can this be accomplished through the Procfile or some heroku addons? Is there a better way to accomplish the desired behavior of button click->Document creation->serve the file? Love to know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few different issues to look at: 1) enabling both Python and Node and then 2) correct use of filesystem on Heroku and 3) ways to schedule the work.

For #1, you need to enable multiple build packs to get both Node.js and Python stacks in place. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app.

For #2, you need to send the files to storage service of some kind (e.g., Amazon S3) - the filesystem for your dyno is ephemeral, and anything written there will disappear after a dyno restart (which happens every 24 hours no matter what)

For #3, the simplest solution is probably the Heroku Scheduler add-on, which acts like a rudimentary cron. Remember, you don't have low-level OS access, so you need to use the Heroku-provided equivalent.